# Algorithm to split a list into an array based on a set of element that are valid for that array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, explode

This is an "optimal algorithm" question.

I need to explode an array A of mixed values 'a', 'b' and 'c' into a new 2 dimensional array B containing the same values but split throughout the 2nd dimension according to the rules below.

B record starts with:

```
a: [a] || [a, a] || [a, b] || [a, b, b]
b: [b] || [b, b] || [b, a] || [b, b, a] || [b, b, b] || [b, b, b, b]
c: [c]
```

- the order is maintained
- each value from A can be used only once in B

So for example I have an array A:

```
['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

and I need to split it into 2-dimensional array B:

```
[
 ['a'],
 ['c'],
 ['b', 'b', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a'],
 ['c'],
 ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
]
```

The code I've written is a lot of nested if/else statements. Code for 'a' only wrapped in while loop:

```
while(i<arrA.length) {
 if(arrA[i] == a) {
  if(arrA[i+1] == a) {
   arrB[] = [arrA[i], arrA[i+1]]; //creates arrB[n]['a', 'a']
   i = i+2;
   continue;
  } elseif (arrA[i+1] == b) {
   if(arrA[i+2] == b) {
    arrB[] = [arrA[i], arrA[i+1], arrA[i+2]]; //creates arrB[n]['a', 'b', 'b']
    i = i+3;
    continue;
   } elseif (arrA[i+2] != b) {
    arrB[] = [arrA[i], arrA[i+1]]; //creates arrB[n]['a', 'b']
    i = i+2;
    continue;
   }
  } elseif (arrA[i+1] == c) {
   arrB[] = [arrA[i]]; //creates arrB[n]['a']
   i++;
   continue;
  }
 } elseif (...)
 i++;
}
```

Code for 'c' is short, for 'b' is longer'.
Is there any algorithm that would be more concise in this situation? If that matters I'm writing this in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tricks to this:

- Any series of if statements checking equality can be reduced to an examination of an array.
- You can loop an remember the 'previous' thing in each loop, and act with that.

That is:

- You can create an array containing all the possible valid combinations
- You can then loop over the sequence array and, at each step check if what you have matches a combination in your list of possibilities.
- If you ever find something that doesn't match, you assume that your previous look matched and put that into your list of matched combinations.

It might not be absolutely optimal - but it's certainly more extensible that what you have at the moment.

```
<?php

    $aPossibleCombinations = array( 'a', 'aa', 'ab', 'abb', 'b', 'bb', 'ba', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbbb', 'c' );

    $aThingsToMatch = array( 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b' );

    $aMatchedThings = array();

    $sPreviousThing = '';
    $sCurrentThing  = '';

    foreach( $aThingsToMatch as $sSingleThing ) {

        $sCurrentThing .= $sSingleThing;

        if ( !in_array( $sCurrentThing, $aPossibleCombinations ) ) {
            $aMatchedThings[] = $sPreviousThing;
            $sCurrentThing = $sSingleThing;
        }

        $sPreviousThing = $sCurrentThing;
    }

    if ( in_array(  $sCurrentThing, $aPossibleCombinations ) ) {
        $aMatchedThings[] = $sPreviousThing;
        $sCurrentThing = '';
    }

    echo( "Matched Things: \r\n" );
    var_dump( $aMatchedThings );

    echo( "Remaining Things: \r\n" );
    var_dump( $sCurrentThing );

?>
```

I should say that I've left one bug in there for you to find.  It works with the current set of `aThingsToMatch`, but it's possible to get it to break.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Many thanks Rob! I implemented it and it works very well. I didn't find any flaw in it . Also, I couldn't find a case in which 'Remaining things' message would be shown.

Comment: Excellent.  Not knowing how the list of things to match or the list of valid combinations are generated I couldn't be sure if it was possible.  It may never be an issue for you, but it may not correctly handle the case where something that's not a valid combination exists in the list (e.g. a 'd')...

Comment: Good point but invalid combination of $aThingsToMatch will not occur in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Just encode the points of decision whether or not to break into a new "line" in a finite state machine. In the code below, the FSM transitions are in `t` and the machine is run
in `f`. I'll draw a picture in a minute, too.

(Yeah, it's C++, but ought to be pretty clear)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int t[12][3] = {
  /*  0 */ { 1,  2, 3 },
  /*  1 */ { 4,  5, 0 }, 
  /*  2 */ { 8,  7, 0 },
  /*  3 */ { 0,  0, 0 },
  /*  4 */ { 0,  0, 0 },
  /*  5 */ { 0,  6, 0 },
  /*  6 */ { 0,  0, 0 },
  /*  7 */ { 9, 10, 0 },
  /*  8 */ { 0,  0, 0 },
  /*  9 */ { 0,  0, 0 },
  /* 10 */ { 0, 11, 0 },
  /* 11 */ { 0,  0, 0 }
};

void
f (const std::string &str, std::vector<std::string> &v) {
    int s = 0;
    int i = 0;
    v.resize(1);
    while (i < str.size()) {
        auto c = str[i];
        auto ns = t[s][c - 'a'];
        if (ns) {
            v.back() += c;
            ++i;
        } else
            v.resize (v.size() + 1);
        s = ns;
    }
}

int
main () {
    std::vector<std::string> a;
    f ("acbbaaacbbbb", a);
    for (auto s : a)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Each time there's no transition from the current state, add a new row in the output array
and go to state 0 without consuming the current character, otherwise add the current character to the current row.

[image]

Comment: I think you may need to explain how to get from the provided set of possible combinations to your array `t` in order for this to make sense at a glance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer chill. I wasn't able to translate your code into my situation but that's due to limited knowledge of C++. When I finish my current work I will take a closer look and leave my feedback.